# iOS TableView/CollectionView split the loading of each item into separate asynchronous operations with different global priorities?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, lazy-loading

I saw a lot of iOS Library to implement asynchonous loading of items in iOS TableView/CollectionView.

But I can not find any library that support below function:

- Multi-part item support: split the loading of each item into separate asynchronous operations with different global priorities.
- Tight integration between user interaction and async loading of items i.e. stops loading items on fling, enables loading when panning with finger down, etc.
- Prefetch items beyond the currently visible items to reduce the number of placeholder-type items while scrolling.

It does all the obvious things you’d expect—loading items as they become visible, cancelling item requests for recycled views, etc. It will avoid wasting item requests after a fling gesture and enable incremental item loading while you scroll the list with finger down. Furthermore, it supports offscreen item preloading to reduce the number of placeholder-type items as you scroll.

With Android I can do all of above fucnctions with [Smoothie](https://github.com/lucasr/smoothie)

Do you have any suggestion about the iOS's library?

Comment: I kind of implemented the functions you listed in my app using `GCD` and `NSURLSession`. `GCD` for async, `NSURLSession` for loading task management (suspend, resume, cancel). It's not very complicated in my app. I didn't make it a library. Making it reusable seems not necessary to me. I only use this strategy for images. Text data must be loaded before rendering table view because table view needs to know layout information like height of each cell.

Comment: And IMO, canceling loading task is a waste of resource. `NSURLSession` caches static data on disk. Using a serial queue to manage image loading tasks and `NSCache` to cache decoded image data in memory works fine. If table view is scrolling quickly or cells contains downloaded image are not visible, then callback just do nothing. But since the data of images are cached in memory (`NSCache`) and disk, they can be rendered when needed very fast.

Comment: @wcd: Could you please give some sample code? Thanks